# FTP clients only showing 9998 folders in a directory with many more

Tags: files, directory, ftp

How can I increase the limit of files or folder in linux? Right now when I use any ftp software it shows that there are only 9998 folder in that directory. But I ran a simple php script that would display all the folders in that directory and it shows that the directory actually holds 70 thousand files. I need to download all those files, but I can only download 9998 files, at least when I'm using FileZilla or Bitvise. Is there a way to increase that limit?

Answer (score 4):

If there are 70000 files but your FTP software only shows 9998, then obviously it's the fault of your FTP software, and there is no limit on the filesystem. You'll need to use another FTP software.

Since you've tried different clients, the problem is presumably the FTP server.

This assumes that your PHP script is correct, of course.

Note that some FTP programs may omit dot files (files whose name begins with `.`) by default.

Manipulating directories with tens of thousands of files gets unwieldy. I recommend that you create other directories and move the files into these new directories. Stick to a few hundred files per directory.

Use a non-buggy FTP program or a PHP script to do this.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but I already tried 4 different ftp clients. this is what I used to show all the actual folders there is in the directory $directory = '/home/matchlat/public_html/media/uploads/9/4/0/0/';
$i = 0;
if ($handle = opendir($directory)) {
    $blacklist = array('.', '..', 'somedir', 'somefile.php');
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
        if (!in_array($file, $blacklist)) {
            echo "$file<br/>";
   $i++;
   
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
echo 'total -----------------------------------';
echo $i;

Comment: another thing is that I tried also to move or copy the files on that folder to another folder in the server and I got an error saying that I couldn't copy more than 9998 files.

Comment: "then obviously it's the fault of your FTP software" is total nonsense. Some FTP server configurations may have this setup to truncate the output list of files to 10000 files so that you can view only 9998 file listed in the directory listing. You should ask your webhost to change the LimitRecursion value.

Comment: @WendiT It _is_ the FTP software. Maybe the client, maybe the server. Presumably the server since the asker tried different clients.

Comment: @Gilles 'SO- stop being evil'
Good to hear there is not difference between software and software settings. Didn't know that. By the way, the question was: How can I increase the limit of files or folder in linux? You didn't answer that question...

Comment: @WendiT There's no such thing as a “limit of files or folder in linux”. It's a limitation in some specific software and the question didn't specify which software was used.

Comment: He means a Linux server

Answer (score 1):

I had to change `pure-ftpd.conf` and increase the `LimitRecursion` setting to support more files.

Comment: This answer should be marked as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue with a folder containing 12000 files.

The way I got around the issue is I logged in via SSH and zipped the directory, then downloaded the zip file.

To ZIP a directory via SSH:

`zip -r myzipfilename.zip /path/to/mydir`